# Need to Load my browser cookies into selenium session

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, session-cookies

I honestly have not found a good answer for this question and the selenium documentation is lacking clarification. The short question is, how do I load cookies that are already in MY chrome browsing window. I don't want to save cookies from session to session I want to load the ones in MY browser. The cookies have a ton of information, what do I add? What do I omit? And if that's not possible, how do I hijack a manual launch of chrome with selenium?

The long question is that I'm trying to use selenium to go to a website already logged in.

The reasons don't really matter other than I'm running tests and I need this to be the case, If I attempt to login thru selenium it requires multiple layers of verification that add too much complexity.

Ideally I could launch chromedriver and just do `driver.add_cookies("name": "keah")` and so forth but that doesn't seem to work or I don't know how to add cookies properly(The cookies I need loaded have around 14 values of information, do I enter all of that?

If so do I enter it under what they are labeled, such as "context", "Accessible to script" and "Expires" or do i just call them "Values". I've also tried adding the user profile thru `options = Options()` and then adding the argument of the chrome user data (which I have no idea where it is, I was copying and pasting based on other information that I found on stackoverflow.).

If I pass the user data to the `webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)`, it fails as no driver found. I suspect I'm not doing it right but I don't have a clue where my chrome data is stored on both my Mac and Windows, So I don't know if my paths are correct.

As you can tell I'm kinda stumbling around the dark I'm hoping for a helping hand to stand me up again. Thanks

Comment: look into loading specific browser profiles.

Comment: I have and when I do that it comes back as a no driver found?? So I'm just reading and reading tell something stands out!! Thanks for the input tho!!

Comment: Post your code!